# Install oracle 11.2.0.4 on windows

Tags: oracle

From this link

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/enterprise-edition/downloads/index.html

The options avaliable are:

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/enterprise-edition/downloads/112010-win32soft-098987.html

there's a 11.2.0.1.0 version and 11.2.0.4 de-install utility, but where is the upgrade utility to pass to 11.2.0.4? Is it possible?

Comment: You can download 11.2.0.4 from ["My Oracle Support"](https://support.oracle.com/) - but you need an Oracle account and a license that allows you to upgrade to 11.2.0.4 for that.

Comment: Add that comment as answer. It is the correct solution